# How can I set the outgoing IPv6 address in Perl's LWP::UserAgent?

Tags: perl, ipv6

I know it is possible to set IPv4 outgoing IP in LWP::UserAgent, but is it possible to set specific IPv6 address as outgoing IP? If yes: how can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upgrade to [Perl 5.14](http://p3rl.org/perl5140delta#Improved-IPv6-support). Its `IO::Socket::INET`/`Socket` modules support IPv6.